# Edit listviewitem of a listview

Tags: c#, listview

I would like to edit an already inserted item in my listview.
Heres exactly what I want to do and have attempted at a fix:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
                return;

            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                String[] split = item.SubItems[0].ToString().Split('{');
                String[] split1 = item.SubItems[1].ToString().Split('{');
                String[] split2 = item.SubItems[2].ToString().Split('{');
                ListViewItem tempitem = new ListViewItem(split[1].Replace("}", ""));
                tempitem.SubItems.Add(split1[1].ToString().Replace("}", ""));
                tempitem.SubItems.Add("0");
                AutoResponce.Remove(split[1].Replace("}", "") + "|" + split1[1].ToString().Replace("}", "") + "|" + split2[1].Replace("}", ""));
                AutoResponce.Add(split[1].Replace("}", "") + "|" + split1[1].ToString().Replace("}", "") + "|" + "0");
                Settings settings = new Settings();
                settings.SaveAuto();
                listView1.Items.Remove(item);
                listView1.Items.Add(tempitem);
            }
```

So I have created a new object with the slight change to the last number input (1 - Enable, 0 -Disabled) and I add it back in but it drags to the bottom of the listview and doesnt look nice what so ever.
Is there a way I can simply edit the input? I usually find a way but apprently I'm lost D:

---

**Fix(Solution):**
This looks stupid but I found a solution.
Not sure if its what people usually do or the correct method but this is what I did:

```
 foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            String[] split = item.SubItems[0].ToString().Split('{');
            String[] split1 = item.SubItems[1].ToString().Split('{');
            String[] split2 = item.SubItems[2].ToString().Split('{');
            ListViewItem tempitem1 = new ListViewItem("1");
            item.SubItems[2] = tempitem1.SubItems[0];
            AutoResponce.Remove(split[1].Replace("}", "") + "|" + split1[1].ToString().Replace("}", "") + "|" + split2[1].Replace("}", ""));
            AutoResponce.Add(split[1].Replace("}", "") + "|" + split1[1].ToString().Replace("}", "") + "|" + "1");
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            settings.SaveAuto();
        }
```

I created a 'tempitem' and set the first subitem to the inputed I intended to be the new input, then set the selected item to the first subitem of the temp item I just created. Seems to have worked perfectly.

Comment: You need to get the index of the item and use `Items.Insert(index, tempitem)`

Comment: Nah index stuff is annoying although I was considering doing it that way but index is a bi messy and confusing for my straight foward way of coding, I seemed to have found a solution to fit my needs anyay, thanks tho<3!